# 'Set as Wallpaper and Lock Screen' PWA android

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, wallpaper, homescreen

I've searched everywhere, but couldn't find an answer.
I'm making PWA app out of an existing Svelte app, targeting androids. When a user clicks on an image (in .png or .jpeg format), I would like for him to have the following options:

- save image (that is working)
- set as homescreen wallpaper
- set as lockscreen wallpaper

Are the last two options possible in PWA-s?

Comment: Have the exact same question, still haven't found an answer 